# How to set auto-offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, when I try to plot points

```
points = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1,),(1,0)]
for point in points:
    plt.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

It will display

[image]

This makes the points hard to see. How can I make the `x`, `y` axis wider so the point would move to the center of the plot? Something like

[image]

That is, how can I set the `offset` value of the points to the bounderies of the `plot`, so they won't be displaed at corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [xlim](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim) and [ylim](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim)

```
points = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1,),(1,0)]

for point in points:
    plt.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o')

automin, automax = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)
automin, automax = plt.ylim()
plt.ylim(automin-0.5, automax+0.5)

plt.show()
```

If you really need to set limits before you plot data you can turn off [autoscaling first](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.autoscale) and then set limits with `xlim` and `ylim`

Answer (score 3):

As @Rob says, you can use

```
plt.xlim([xmin, xmax])
plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

It's also worth noting that it's much more efficient to plot all your x values vs all your y values.

```
points = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
xs, ys = zip(*points)
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'o')
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.ylim([-1, 2])
plt.show()
```

If you want separate colors for each point, you could use `scatter`:

```
points = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1,),(1,0)]
xs, ys = zip(*points)
colors = range(len(xs))
plt.scatter(xs, ys, c=colors)
plt.xlim([-1, 2])
plt.ylim([-1, 2])
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT**: Additionally, it turns out that since you want to plot points, you should use `scatter` instead of `plt` because it automatically adjusts the limits for you.  The moral: use the appropriate tool for the job.  See below (ignore my weird matplotlibrc settings):

```
points = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
for point in points:
    plt.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
points = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
plt.scatter(*zip(*points))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But is there  any helper that I can use to set the `xlim`, `ylim` value? If there is not such a thing, then I'll have to set it manually everytime I plot?

Comment: Another problem, `matplot` does not support plot by point? And favors `zip`? Its another convention to learn.

Comment: @cqcn1991 And `matplotlib` does support plot by point, you've seen it does in your OP.  I was just commenting on how to more efficiently plot lots of points.

Comment: @cqcn1991 If you use `scatter` instead of `plot` to plot points, it will automatically rescale the axes limits.  This is because `plot` is traditionally used for plotting lines (points optional), and typically with line plots you don't want empty space at the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ylim and xlim parameters. e.g.

```
plt.ylim(-1,5)
plt.xlim(-1,5)
plt.show()
```